# Match Regex in MySQL for repeated word in one column

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I'm having a query problem. I use mysql as DB.
I want to use a REGEX to match the result I expected
and The Table is

```
table A

----------------------------------
|   ID  | Description            |
----------------------------------
|   1   |  new 2 new 2 new 2 new |
|   2   |   new 2 new 2 new      |
|   3   |   new 2                |
|   4   |   2 new 2new           |
```

The Result I expected

```
---------------------------------
|   ID  | Description           |
---------------------------------
|   2   |   new 2 new 2 new     |
|   4   |   2 new 2new          |
```

The Query I've tried so far:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE (description REGEXP '([^2][^0..9]])2( [^2][^0..9])([^2][^0..9]])2( [^2][^0..9])')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d712/2

Could anyone help me to solve this :(?

Comment: whats so special in the output ?

Comment: why shouldn't row 1 be matched?

Comment: Can you describe what you want your regex to do? *Why* did you expect it would return that result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tim Pietzcker pointed out, your regular expression does not do what you may think it does. If I understand correctly, I believe you are looking for the following regular expression. This returns ID `2` and `4` respectively.

```
^[^2]*2[^2]*2[^2]*$
```

Your SQL query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE (description REGEXP '^[^2]*2[^2]*2[^2]*$')
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d712/6/0)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex isn't doing what you think it does (although I can't quite guess *what* you think it does...)

A translation of part of your regex:

```
([^2][^0..9]])2
```

means:

```
(         # Start a group
 [^2]     # Match one character except "2"
 [^0..9]  # Match one character except "0", "." or "9"
 ]        # Match "]"
)         # End of group
2         # Match "2"
```